# How to work out the Transition matrix corresponding to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ = $\left\lbrace \pmatrix{1\\1},\pmatrix{2\\3} \right\rbrace$ be a basis of $U = \mathbb{R}^2$, (the column space),  and consider another basis $B'$ = $\left\lbrace \pmatrix{3\\1},\pmatrix{7\\2} \right\rbrace$

Find the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$, and label it as $P$.

> I know if $B$ was the standard basis then $P= \pmatrix{3&7\\1&2}$

What is the calculation to do, when the first basis is not standard. What should P be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you must write make B and B' as columns of a Gaussian array, and attempt to reduce B to a reduced row echelon form, while applying the same elementary operations to B', you will find that B' will have transformed in your change of basis matrix P. Sorry for not doing any calculations on MathJax, it might have been a bit long winded.

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there. Think about how you might perform this change of basis in two steps: first go from $B$ to the standard basis, then from the standard basis to $B'$. What matrix operations correspond to these two steps?